# Does using STL increase footprint significantly?

Tags: c++, stl

Does using STL increase footprint significantly? Could you guys share your experience regarding this matter? What are the best practices to build a small footprint library?

Answer (score 20):

There's no one answer since STL is a set of templates.  Templates, by their very nature, are only compiled in when used.  So you can include all of STL and if none of it is actually used, the footprint added by STL will be zero.  If you have a very small app that manages to use a lot of different templates with different specializations, the footprint can be large.

Comment: Very good answer. Taking this a step further, the STL solution could even be *smaller* if the code written to avoid using STL isn't actually used.

Answer (score 11):

The thing about the STL because it is all templates it only adds to the size when you actually use. If you don't use a method then that method is not instantiated.

But there will always be a cost for the things you use.

But the real question you have to ask. Is the size going to be bigger or smaller than yourt own implementation? If you don't use the STL what do you use? You can hand write your own but that has its own cost. It is not zero space, it will not be well tested and you will not be following the established best practices.

So in reality no it does not bloat your code.
Because to add the equivalent functionality by some other method will add just as much code it just will not be as well tested.

Other post states that template code must be in-lined or have multiple definitions.
This is absolutely **WRONG**.

The methods are marked as in-line. But it is up to the compiler if the method is actually in-lined or not. The compiler inlining is sophisticated enough to only in-line if this will help in the optimization stratergy being used.

If not in-lined then a copy of the method will be generated in every compilation unit that uses the method. But a REQUIREMENT for a C++ linker is that it must remove ALL but ONE copy of these methods when the application is linked into an executable. If the compiler did not remove the extra copies it would have to generate a multiple definition linker error.

This is easy to show:
The following illustrates that:

- The method _M_insert_aux() is not in-lined.
- It is placed in both compilation units.
- That only one copy of the method is in the final executable.

#### a.cpp

```
#include <vector>

void a(std::vector<int>& l)
{
    l.push_back(1);
    l.at(0) = 2;
}
```

#### b.cpp

```
#include <vector>

void b(std::vector<int>& l)
{
    l.push_back(1);
    l.at(0) = 2;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <vector>

void a(std::vector<int>&);
void b(std::vector<int>&);

int main()
{
    std::vector<int>    x;
    a(x);
    b(x);
}
```

#### Checking

```
>g++ -c a.cpp
>g++ -c b.cpp

>nm a.o
<removed other stuff>
000000a0 S __ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi
<removed other stuff>

>nm b.o
<removed other stuff>
000000a0 S __ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi
<removed other stuff>

>c++filt __ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)

>g++ a.o b.o main.cpp
nm a.out | grep __ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi
00001700 T __ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi
```

Comment: For the purposes of accurately answering the original question, I think we need to know more about the OP's environment.  My post is worst-case, your post is most-common-case.  Enlightening, though, and a bit scary.  If a.cxx is compiled -Os and b.cxx is compiled -O3, the functions clearly differ.

Comment: Does the compiler guarantee binary compatability between objects compiled with different flags? (I don't know). This is one reason why IDE's (via Targets) build all -Os objects into one directory and all -O3 into another directory and only link together objects built using the same flags.

Answer (score 4):

Using the STL will increase your binary size for two basic reasons:

#### Inlining

By default, the compiler treats template code as inline.  Therefore, if you use `std::list<int>` in several different compilation units, *and the compiler inlines that code*, they'll each have their own local inline definitions of `std::list<int>` functions (which probably isn't a big deal, since the compiler will only inline very small definitions by default).

Note that (as Martin points out elsewhere) multiply-defined symbols are stripped out by all modern C++ linkers on the big platforms, as described in the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html#Template-Instantiation).  Thus, if the compiler leaves template code out-of-line, the linker will remove duplicates.

#### Specialization

Because of of the very nature of C++ templates, `std::list<int>` is potentially arbitrarily different than `std::list<double>`.  In fact, the standard mandates that `std::vector<bool>` is defined as a bit-vector, so most of the operations there are *completely* different than the default `std::vector<T>`.

Only the library maintainer can deal with this.  One solution is to take the core functionality and "un-templatize" it.  Turn it into a C-style data structure with `void*` everywhere.  Then, the template interface that downstream developers see is a thin wrapper.  The reduces the amount of duplicated code because the template specializations all share a common basis.

Comment: You forget to mention that only the templates or specializations that are actually used will be compiled into the binary, and inlining can reduce code size as well (if a function is only called once, inlining it results in smaller code than not inlining).

Comment: Jalf - those issues apply to all C or C++ software, not just templates.  But that's a good point as well.

Comment: Your in-lining argument does not hold. A method is marked as inline if it is defined in the class declaration. But it is still up to the compiler weather the code is actually in-lined or not. If it will significantly increase the size of the code it will not be in-lined.

Comment: Yes std::list<int> is different from std::list<double> so you will have two different version. But how would you implement the same functionality in your own code? You implement two different types and hay presto you are in the same position as if you had used templates.

Comment: Even if the compiler decides not to inline the template function, you will still get a copy in each compilation unit. If you have a lot of units that use std::list<int>, that's a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: Martin - yes, the in-lining absolutely does hold.  Even if a compiler decides std::vector<int>::push_back() should be out-of-line, it will be defined in every single compilation unit that uses it.  Thus, it is still duplicated in the final binary unless you have a sophisticated linker.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: ABSOLUTELY FALSE. Yes it is duplicated but at link time all but one MUST be removed, otherwise there would be linker errors. So if it is not in-lined there will be only ONE copy of each method.

Comment: @Tom: Yes the linker is sophisticated. This is a REQUIREMENT of being able to link C++. Try it dump the symbols from the resulting application you will only find ONE version of each method.

Comment: Please see my post for an explanation of why your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @Mark - You are 100% correct, with GNU ld and GCC.  Not all compilers and linkers do that (quick googling shows Sun CC on Solaris 9 behaved poorly).

Here's a discussion that explains why ld can't always just throw out multiple definitions:

http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2002-02/msg00142.html

Comment: @Tom: Again not quite correct. The sun compiler just takes a different tack. Rather than putting the template method definitions in the compilation unit it uses a temporary cache directory. Thus eliminating duplicates by using file-names to represent methods.

Comment: @Tom: But the discussion you quote is 6 years old and totally out of date.

Comment: @Martin: If you can point to me something authoritative that describes how conforming C++ linkers are required to resolve this, I'll pull the inlining discussion.  I'd like to know what's supposed to happen when the function bodies differ.

Comment: The linker is not required to throw out the duplicate bodies of code, only the duplicate symbol definitions. Linkers traditionally have only been able to delete whole modules. It would be good to test a few to find out what they do.

Comment: Dave Delaney's answer provides a link describing the "Borland" system - template instantiations are put into common blocks which the linker will collapse. Interesting approach, gives me hope that the compiler/linker are smarter than I thought.

Comment: @Tom: http://developer.apple.com/documentation/developertools/gcc-3.3/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html

Comment: @Tom: All compilers/linkers will only guarantee the executable is valid iff all objects are built with the same flags. This is NOT a template problem, it is a general problem that affects all parts of the language. This is why IDEs build different versions (debug/release) in different directories.

Comment: MSVC will merge functions if the assembly is identical. So list<int>::push_back and list<void*>::push_back are often merged, as both copy 32 bits without looking.

Comment: @Martin - I've always thought it was valid to build compilation units with differing compiler flags, provided they are binary compatible.  Is that still valid if all function bodies are defined out-of-line?

Comment: @Martin - the GNU docs you (and Dave Delaney) pointed to indicate that on some systems, GNU ld will *not* handle automatic template instantiation.  Does this just mean that explicit instantiation is *required* to avoid multiply-defined symbols on those platforms?

Comment: @Tom: Yes binary compatibility is the issue. But which flags change this. This is why in IDE's (who take the safe course) build each target in separate directories. And all objects for a target are built using the same flags. But this is not specifically a template issue.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean runtime **memory** footprint, and thusly STL **containers**.

STL containers are efficient for what they are...general purpose containers.  If you are deciding between writing your own doubly-linked list or using std::list, please...use STL.  If you are considering writing very domain-specific, bit-packed containers for each of your specific needs, use STL first and then choose your battles once all your code is working correctly.

Some good practices:

- **If your library is going to expose these containers via the API, you may have to choose between putting your STL code in library headers or not using STL.  The problem is that my compiler doesn't have to implement the STL the same way yours did.**
- Read up on how and when STL
  containers allocate memory.  When
  you can visualize how a deque grows
  and shrinks compared to a vector,
  you will be better prepared to decide which to use.
- If you need to micro-manage every byte, consider writing custom allocators.  This is rarely necessary outside of embedded systems.

Answer (score 2):

While it does not address STL templates, the documentation for GCC has short section on minimizing code bloat when using templates templates.

The link is 
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html#Template-Instantiation

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the STL discussion for the moment, there is one non-obvious important practice for building a low-space-footprint static library.  Partition your library into as many disparate compilation units as you can.  For example, if you look at `libpthread.a`, you'll see that every single function has its own compilation unit.  Many linkers will throw out dead code based on whole compilation units, but not any more fine-grained than that.  If I only use a few functions from the pthreads library, my linker will bring in only those definitions, and nothing else.  If, on the other hand, the entire library were compiled into a single object file, my linker would have to bring in the entire library as a single "unit".

This depends on the toolchain you're using, and it only applies if you're building static libraries.  But I have seen it make a very measurable difference for large libraries built sub-optimally.

Answer (score 1):

STL specializations based on pointers can share the same implementation.  This is since (void *) has the same size as (int *) or (foo *).  So while:

vector⟨int⟩ and vector⟨foo⟩ are different implementations.

vector⟨int *⟩ and vector⟨foo *⟩ can share much of the same implementation.  Many STL implementations do this to save memory footprint.

If the entire template is defined in a header so it is completely defined, compilers like g++ will automatically create a copy in each compilation unit using the class.  As the others said, the linker will remove multiple definitions.

They will also automatically inline the methods in the class definition, for the higher optimization levels.  But this can be controlled with compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

On an embedded project with a 64kb limit I once did, I couldn't even link the standard C libraries. So it depends on what you need to do